# Changing image SRC using javascript - unknown error

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript for the first time and am having difficulty getting certain features to work. Crucially I can't seem to get the following line of code to execute.

```
document.getElementByID("reportImage").src=filepath;
```

The full code is given below.

Notice that I've created a test function to try and narrow down the cause of the malfunction. The first two functions are there to demonstrate intent but are not currently being called by the .

The behavior of the test function suggests that the error is within this specific line. Notably the alert will fire if it is placed first in the function but will not trigger if placed second (suggesting that this specific line is problematic in some way).

It may be a simple syntax error but I've checked many times and can't see what it might be. Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>

/* declare and set script variables */
var numberOfImages, imageArray, timing, containingFolder, i;
i = -1;
timing = 3;
containingFolder = "H:\\Images";
imageArray = [
    "FoxKey.jpg",
    "TeamKPI2.tif"
]; //imageArray should contain names of image files that sit within the specified folder

numberOfImages = imageArray.length;

function activateImageTimer() {
/* function iterates through selected images */ 
    if (numberOfImages === timingArray.length) {
        setInterval(nextImage(), timing*10);
    }
    else { alert("Please check contents of imageArray and timingArray. The 
number of images should correspond to the number of timings."); }
}

function nextImage() {
    i = (i+1) % numberOfImages;  //use modulus function to loop through array
    var filepath = containingFolder + "\\" + imageArray[i]; //build filepath
    document.getElementByID("reportImage").src=filepath;
}

function testFunction() {
document.getElementByID("reportImage").src="H:\\Images\\FoxKey.jpg";
alert("Function is functioning");
}
</script>

<body onload="testFunction()">
<img id="reportImage" src="H:\Images\TeamKPI2.tif">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`.

Comment: Try `src="file://H:\Images\TeamKPI2.tif"`.  You need to use the `file://` protocol.  Bear in mind that you really ***shouldn't*** use the `file://` protocol

Comment: Next time, please try to be more specific on the kind of `unknown error` you're getting. Seems like just by opening the dev tools you're able to see the exact error message.

Comment: Also, `<script>` cannot go directly inside `<html>`.  [The *only* elements allowed as direct descendents of the HTML element are `head` and `body`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html)

Comment: Try `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementByID`

Comment: First comment is a perfect fix! Apologies for such a trivial problem but I wouldn't have worked that out on my own (nor do I have dev tools, this is a one off job on a work computer so I've been making do with notepad).

Comment: @P.Hopkinson What?  You have dev tools.  Every web browser has dev tools.  The usual keyboard shortcut is F12.  It's also available from the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JavaScript is Case Sensitive**.

Try with this:

Change: `document.getElementByID` to `document.getElementById`

And, `<script></script>` **it has to be put inside the `body` or `head`, not of `html`**.